# Change tolerance in array comparison

Tags: arrays, matlab, comparison

I have the following issue. I have to compare an array of floating point numbers (A) with a variable (B). Such as

```
A = [0.0032,  0.12 , 0.53 1.43]
B = 0.00321
```

But in this case, B is slightly different from A(1). Not using a for, how can I set the tolerance and get a result such as:

```
ans = [1 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a `tolerance` and check if the diff is less than your tolerance.

```
tolerance = 1e-4;
abs(A-B) < tolerance
```